# Modifying querystring on asp:hyperlink?

Tags: asp.net

My code looks like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl="Search.aspx?txtGraphicNumber=" target="_blank" runat="server">Search Related</asp:HyperLink>
```

My querystring starts with "txtGraphiNumber=".  What I'd like to do is append to this querystring the information in a field on the screen.  The field is called txtGraphicNumber.

Can I do something like:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl="Search.aspx?txtGraphicNumber=" + txtGraphicNumber + " " target="_blank" runat="server">Search Related</asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options to achieve the same:

**Option 1# Code behind:**

```
//assuming txtGraphicNumber is a textbox.
HyperLink1.NavigateUrl += txtGraphicNumber.text;
```

**Option 2# InlineCode:**

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl='<%="Search.aspx?txtGraphicNumber=" +   
 txtGraphicNumber.value %>' target="_blank" runat="server">Search Related
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it from code-behind:

```
HyperLink1.NavigateUrl += txtGraphicNumber;
```

If `txtGraphicNumber` is a literal string value. You could use inline ASP.NET script for constructing primitive HTML controls and their values/attributes but this doesn't play nice with managed server-side controls.